# PHP: How to find a big word in a small one

Tags: php, find, preg-match

I have user input like:
`$name = 'Alexxxx'`
Or
`$name = 'Aaaalex'`

And I have list of names like:
`$names = 'Jack Harry Alex Oscar'`

I need to know that user input contains name from a list, but user can input 'raw' name. How I can check it?

I've tried variants like this. But all of this find half input name in List. While I need the other way around

```
preg_match(
    '/(.*)' . $name . '(.*)/',
    $this->listOfNames,
);
```

```
str_contains(
    $this->listOfNames, strtolower(trim($name))
);
```

```
strstr($this->listOfNames, $name) !== false;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `half input name`? If `Alexxxx` is inputted you want `Alex` returned because of match in `$names`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping that I've understood correctly, if not, please do correct me in comments!

My understanding is that you want to know whether a user-inputted string contains at least one of the names listed in a string (separated by a space). For example, search `Alexxxx` for `Jack` `Harry` `Alex` or `Oscar` which is of course `true` because `Alexxxx` contains `Alex`.

On the other hand, inputting `Bruno` would return `false`.

If I've understood correctly, the key would be to split the string of names using `explode` by the space as delimiter, then iterate through each item checking it against the inputted string.

```
<?php
$inputName = 'Alexxxx';
$names = 'Jack Harry Alex Oscar';

//Get an array of the names from $name. Result: ["Jack","Harry","Alex","Oscar"]
$listOfNames = explode(" ", $names);

// Initially we're going to filter our new array ($listOfNames) 
//   and pass in the $inputName using "use". 
// The filter callback merely checks for string position using strpos, 
//   case insensitivity requires stripos.
// This will return ["Alex"] is this example. 
// A simple count() > 0 logic check will give us a true/false outcome 
//   stored in $inputFoundInList. count() will be zero is not found.

$inputFoundInList = count(array_filter($listOfNames, function ($name) use ($inputName) {
    return strpos($inputName, $name) !== FALSE;
})) > 0;

// Result will be 1 (or true)
echo $inputFoundInList;
```